# Type 'Promise<string[]>' is not assignable to type 'string[]'

Tags: angular

Getting following error:
**Type 'Promise<string[]>' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Promise<string[]>'.**

when i cast Promise<string[]> to type 'string[]'
My code below,

**Component: app.dashboard.ts**

```js
    import {Component} from '@angular/core';
    import { MemberService } from "./app.service";
    @Component({
    selector:'app-root',
    templateUrl:'./app.dashboard.html',
    providers:[MemberService]
              })

    export class AppDashboard{
      title='Dashboard'
      constructor(private memberService: MemberService) { }

      public doughnutChartLabels:string[] = 
        this.memberService.getmemberheader();//error occurred here
      }
    }
```

**Service:app.service.ts**

```js
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Member } from './Member';
    import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams } from'@angular/http';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

    @Injectable()
    export class MemberService
    {
      constructor(private http: Http) {
      }
    
      private getHeaders(){
        // I included these headers because otherwise FireFox
        // will request text/html instead of application/json
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
        return headers;
      }
      
      getmemberheader(): Promise<string[]> {
        return this.http
            .get(`/ReportService/MemberDatabaseCountryname`, {headers: this.getHeaders()})
            .toPromise()
            .then(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
      }  

      private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
       
        return body || {};
      }
      private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.error('An error occurred', error);
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Assume your response from `http.get` is an array, here you are returning `Promise` from  function `memberService.getmemberheader`, you should retrieve result of promise at its `then` callback instead (not assigning promise itself to array `doughnutChartLabels`).

```
public doughnutChartLabels: string[];

this.memberService.getmemberheader().then(res => {
  this.doughnutChartLabels = res;
})
```

Comment: Can you more explain it please.

Comment: @levolutionniste I think I have explained enough at my answer. Any way, OP's `getmemberheader` function return a `Promise<[]>` not `[]` itself. Check it again. :-)

Comment: Is it possible to declare `this.doughnutChartLabels = this.memberService.getmemberheader();` ?

Comment: @Lobato Not possible, `this.memberService.getmemberheader()` returns a promise, not the real data.

Answer (score 1):

@levolutionniste

The function getmemberheader() returns a promise.

The main motivation for promises is to bring synchronous style error handling to Async / Callback style code.  ES6 has adopted this spec for its Promise implementation. Promises have a special syntax that allows promises to be daisy-chained together, allowing the results from one promise to feed the next promise.

So:

```js
getmemberheader()
.then((returnsAStringArrayObjectHere_YouCanCallItAnythingYouLike) => {
 // Do something with this array here
})
.catch((error) => {
 console.log("Oops something went wrong: ", error);
});
```

Here are some articles on promises:

- https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/promise.html - my favourite.
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

So getmemberheader will return a promise of type string[].

```js
this.memberService.getmemberheader().then(res => {
  this.doughnutChartLabels = res;
})
```

This is why on the **middle line** the variable **res** contains the string[] from getmemberhead promise. Then in the code block {} the user sets a field doughnutChartLabels to this variable res.

Promises are great to use especially when working with ORM's which often return promises, making it easy to daisy-chain them together - which ensures that the code runs synchronously from left to right throughout the promise chain.