# TypeScript: Type error when using get()-Method from HttpClient and subscribe to it

Tags: angular, typescript

in my Angular app I established a service which fetches some data from a MongoDB as a json-Array. This is the code of my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class IdeaServiceService {

  private _getURL = '/api/1.0.0/ideas';

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  getIdeas() {
    return this._http.get(this._getURL).map((response: Response) => response.json());
  }

}
```

In another component I try to subscribe to this services and store the fetched data into an array of Idea (respective class which I established). This is the corresponding code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Idea} from '../idea';
import {IdeaServiceService} from '../idea-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ideas-overview',
  templateUrl: './ideas-overview.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ideas-overview.component.css'],
  providers: [IdeaServiceService]
})

export class IdeasOverviewComponent implements OnInit {

  ideas: Array<Idea>;

  constructor(private _ideaService: IdeaServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._ideaService.getIdeas().subscribe(resIdeaData => this.ideas = resIdeaData);
  }
}
```

Now the following type error occurs:

**Error:(19, 59) TS2322:Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'Idea[]'.
  Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Promise'.**

Thanks a lot for your support!

Comment: this should give you an hint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45430356/type-promisestring-is-not-assignable-to-type-string

Comment: @Patrick The new `HttpClient` by default formats the response to JSON so we no longer need to parse it using `response.json()`

Comment: @Vikas: I understand. What would this mean concretely for my code? Do I just take away the .json()-Method? This does not work.

Comment: This might help in this case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43008411/typeerror-error-json-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 0):

response.json() returns a Promise and not a plain Array as you await. So you have to use then() in addition:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._ideaService.getIdeas().subscribe(jsonPromise => {
       jsonPromise.then(resIdeaData => {
          this.ideas = resIdeaData;
       });
    });
}
```

Comment: This seems to work. At least my TypeScript code does not retrieve any error anymore now.

But now I have the issue that my browser throws an error when building the app an open it in the browser:

**The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. home**

Comment: Just put a console.log('resIdeaData : ', resIdeaData); inside. Then you'll see the whether works. ;).  Please mark this answer as solution if it helped you.

Comment: I do declare the character encoding in my index.html:

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Comment: In Google Chrome it works but now I have the following TypeError:

**TypeError: response.json is not a function**

Comment: This might help in that case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43008411/typeerror-error-json-is-not-a-function